# How can I get WinPower 3.2.0.2 to find my UPS on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, ups, ubuntu-11.10

How can I get WinPower 3.2.0.2 to find my UPS on Linux?

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10
I have an Advice UPS

After install WinPower, it cannot detect the UPS which is connected with USB cable.